# Dynamize range of SAS PROC SQL SELECT INTO macro creation

Tags: sql, select, sas, select-into

I want to put multiple observations into an own macro variable. I would do this by using select into :obs1 - :obs4, however, as count of observations can differ, i would like to dynamize the range and my code looks like this:

```
proc sql;
    create table segments as select distinct substr(name,1,6) as segment from dictionary.columns
    where libname = 'WORK' and memname = 'ALL_CCFS' and name ne 'MONTH';
run;

proc sql noprint;
    select count(*) into: count from segments;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    select segment into :segment_1 - :segment_&count. from dictionary.columns;
run;
```

However, this doesn't seem to work... any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Leave last value empty/blank and SAS will create them automatically
- Set it to an absurdly large number and SAS will only use what's required
- Use a data step to create it where you can dynamically increment your number (not shown).

  ```
  proc sql noprint;
  select segment into :segment_1 - 
  from dictionary.columns;
  run;


  proc sql noprint;
  select segment into :segment_1 - :segment_999
  from dictionary.columns;
  run;
  ```

Comment: And save the automatic macro variable SQLOBS into your own macro variable (COUNT for example) to remember how many were created.